# Make: Change all extensions to .o

Tags: makefile, gnu, file-extension

I have a makefile, and in that I have an array called `SOURCES`. In this array, there are a c files and there are c++ files. However I want to change every path's extension in that array, no matter whether it is c or c++ to `.o`. How could I do this? I know that to change one extension to another I could do this: `OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)`, but I want to do this for c++ files as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple different options.

Use [`$(filter)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-filter)/[`$(filter-out)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-filter_002dout) and do the substitution twice:

```
OBJECTS := $(filter %.o,$(SOURCES:.c=.o))
OBJECTS += $(filter %.o,$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))
```

Or, if you know that you only have `.c` and `.cpp` files in `SOURCES` (or want to support other extensions in `SOURCES` being converted to `.o`) you could use [`$(basename)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-basename) and [`$(addsuffix)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-suffix):

```
OBJECTS := $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SOURCES)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:`.cpp`=.o)

for file extension `.cpp` ,

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions